# What secondary status icons are in Trillian Astra?

Tags: icons, trillian

Im using trillian astra. A secondary status icon annoys me. I have not idea what the meaning is of it. Its like a triangle, and its white-yellow. Can anyone help me to find out what it is exactly?

Comment: I've wanted to know this too - I always thought it was the away/idle icons over the user's picture. But, alas, it is not!

Answer (score 1):

Secondary icons can be block/alert/warnings.  Perhaps you added a notification for when that user signs on - right click the contact and look for menu options to modify/delete notifications.  You may also have blocked that user.

Include a picture and it will be easier to diagnose.

You can hide all secondary icons by unchecking Trillian Prefs > Contact List > Show secondary status icons.